# ScrollTo on ListView works not directly after setting view visible

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I'm trying to copy the android date picker with xamarin forms as a user control in form of a dialog, as for practice purpose and because I honestly hate the iPhone date picker... Anyways for now everything works fine, I can choose a day, switch between months, select a year, etc.

But there is just a single small annoying problem I can't solve on my own by now.
The starting ui of the date contains the Year and the selected day like

> 2017 - Wed, 22. February

If the user taps on the year, the day picker will be hidden and a listView with the available years is shown. This also works fine, my problem is I want to scroll to the selected year if tapped on the year presented. But this works only if I tap twice on the year.

So let's say the user taps on "2017", he is now presented the list view and it's not scrolled and shows the very first item at top. Now he taps the "2017" again and finally the listView scrolls to the position so that the item with "2017" is shown in the center for the user.
Maybe the image below explains it a bit better (Start -> First tap on 2017 -> Second tap on 2017)
[image: Start -> First tap on 2017 -> Second tap on 2017]

Am I doing something wrong, is there something I fail to see? Could it may be that the height is responsible for that behavior if the listview itself is not visible?

Note: I already tried to call `scrollTo` with setting of the `SelectedDate` or while creating the actual view (ie in constructor or `OnBindingContextChanged`).

Note2: the `if(sender == YearLabel)` check is true at the first time and `selection` is not null but the same value as the second time

important part of XAML

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" Spacing="5" Padding="15" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedDate, StringFormat='{0:yyyy}', Source={x:Reference this}}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="LightGray" x:Name="YearLabel">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDateLabelTapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedDate, StringFormat='{0:ddd, d. MMMM}', Source={x:Reference this}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" x:Name="DayLabel">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDateLabelTapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout x:Name="YearPicker" IsVisible="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
            <ListView ItemSelected="OnYearSelected" x:Name="YearList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dateDataTemplateSelector}" SeparatorVisibility="None" />
            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="#efefef" />
        </StackLayout>
    ... other stuff
```

in code behind

```
public ObservableCollection<YearViewModel> Years { get; set; }

public DateTime SelectedDate
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
}

private void OnDateLabelTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if(sender == YearLabel)
        {
            YearLabel.TextColor = Color.White;
            DayLabel.TextColor = Color.LightGray;
            YearPicker.IsVisible = true;
            DayPicker.IsVisible = false;

            var selection = Years.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date.Year == SelectedDate.Year);
            YearList.ScrollTo(selection, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
        }
        else if(sender == DayLabel)
        {
            DayLabel.TextColor = Color.White;
            YearLabel.TextColor = Color.LightGray;
            DayPicker.IsVisible = true;
            YearPicker.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

If you think more code could be helpful, please let me know!

Comment: Does it enter the `if` the first time you click it ?

Comment: Yes it does, and `selection` is not null

Comment: My advice is try to do a mocklist and try to reproduce the problem in a smaller scaller, to make sure your logic is not faulted at some point.. Let me know how it turns out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since I was debugging this again and again my guess that it could be because of missing height of the listView directly after setting `YearPicker.IsVisible = true;` was right. I am a bit annoyed by myself, that I didn't see this before, but ok.

My current solution is

```
private void OnDateLabelTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if(sender == YearLabel)
        {
            YearLabel.TextColor = Color.White;
            DayLabel.TextColor = Color.LightGray;
            YearPicker.IsVisible = true;
            DayPicker.IsVisible = false;

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20), () =>
            {
                var selection = Years.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date.Year == SelectedDate.Year);
                YearList.ScrollTo(selection, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
                return false;
            });
        }
        else if(sender == DayLabel)
        {
            DayLabel.TextColor = Color.White;
            YearLabel.TextColor = Color.LightGray;
            DayPicker.IsVisible = true;
            YearPicker.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

so basically I just wait a few milliseconds to make sure the listview has calculated its height and displays every entry.

Since this feels **a lot** like a hack I would appreciate any other/better solution for this.
I already tried listening to the `sizeChanged` event of the listView but with no result whatsoever

```
YearList.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            var selection = Years.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Date.Year == SelectedDate.Year);
            YearList.ScrollTo(selection, ScrollToPosition.Center, true);

        };
```